# How do I display form properties in a message box?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following code, which should loop through all the forms in the project, and give a messagebox with the settings for each form.  I know the loop is correct, because I use the loop elsewhere and I just copied it.  Why is the messagebox blank?

```
   For Each frm In CurrentProject.AllForms
         DoCmd.OpenForm frm.Name, acDesign

        mess = "Form: " & frm.Name & vbCrLf & " Allow Addition: " & CStr(frm.AllowAdditions) & vbCrLf & "Allow Deletions: " & CStr(frm.AllowDeletions) & vbCrLf & "     Allow Edit: " & CStr(frm.AllowEdits)
        MsgBox (mess)
        DoCmd.Close acForm, frm.Name, acSaveYes

  Next frm
  Set frm = Nothing
```

With Remou's tips, I got the following to work:

```
  For Each frm In CurrentProject.AllForms
     DoCmd.OpenForm frm.Name, acDesign
    Set frm = Forms(frm.Name)
    mess = "Form: " & frm.Name & vbCrLf & " Allow Addition: " & CStr(frm.AllowAdditions) & vbCrLf & "Allow Deletions: " & CStr(frm.AllowDeletions) & vbCrLf & "     Allow Edit: " & CStr(frm.AllowEdits)
    MsgBox (mess)
        DoCmd.Close acForm, frm.Name, acSaveNo

  Next frm
  Set frm = Nothing
```

Comment: You really do not want acSaveYes.

Comment: @Remou- No, your right.  I figured this out by copying something that does change the form.  Here I'm just reading it.

Comment: @HansUp The last sample works for me in Access 2010, which, I admit, is somewhat surprising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access form properties without opening the form. You should only use Set with objects, not with strings.

See [Access 2010: Which form control fires a macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732748/access-2010-which-form-control-fires-a-macro/10733311#comment13943735_10733311)

```
For Each f In CurrentProject.AllForms
    DoCmd.OpenForm f.Name, acDesign

    Set frm = Forms(f.Name)
    mess = "Form: " & frm.Name & vbCrLf
    mess = mess & " Allow Addition: " & CStr(frm.AllowAdditions) & vbCrLf
    mess = mess & "Allow Deletions: " & CStr(frm.AllowDeletions) & vbCrLf
    mess = mess & "     Allow Edit: " & CStr(frm.AllowEdits)
    MsgBox mess

    DoCmd.Close acForm, f.Name, acSaveNo
Next
```

Comment: The Forms aren't open, but see my edit above which also didn't work with the same result.

Comment: Have a better look at the link I posted. The frm from AllForms is not the same as a form object. You cannot OpenForm frm, you cannot refer to frm properties.

Comment: No, you just need to refer to the form object, not to frm from AllForms.